# Are there any good Unit Test frameworks for Ada?

Tags: unit-testing, ada

I come from a C++ background, but I'm currently working in Ada. In the C++ world, I unit test every class as I write it... this doesn't seem to be the vogue for our codebase here at work.

I'd like to start implementing unit tests for the Ada packages I create, are there any good frameworks out there that do this?

Answer (score 10):

There are two open source JUnit-like unit testing frameworks around, [AUnit](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/aunit/) and [Ahven](http://ahven.sourceforge.net/).

AUnit is good if you use Ada 2005 and GNAT compiler family. Downside is that you cannot use it in Ada 95 projects. Ahven fills the gap and concentrates on being compatible with various Ada 95 compilers (like older GNAT compilers, Janus/Ada, ObjectAda).

(PS. I am author of Ahven.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that AUnit does not support Ada95 code.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [AUnit](https://libre.adacore.com/aunit/main.html)

Answer (score 3):

tkoskine says that AUnit doesn't support Ada95; don't know where that came from, I've been using AUnit for the last 8 years on a project which is still Ada95!

Comment: I was wrong about that.
AUnit 3.* needs an Ada 2005 compiler that understands pragma Ada_2005 in a unit to mean "this unit uses 05 features, but that's OK even if you're compiling in 95 mode". That means GNAT.
This might be fixable.

Answer (score 2):

[VectorCAST/Ada](http://www.vectorcast.com/software-testing-products/ada-unit-testing.php) has been around for awhile.